# Can't remove special characters with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace, html-encode

I have a very trivial problem with str_replace.

I have a string with the En Dash character ( - ) like this:

```
I want to remove - the dash
```

The html output is

```
I want to remove the &ndash; the dash
```

I want to do this:

```
$new_string = str_replace ('-','',$string);
```

I've tried to parse the string with html_entity_decode, to parse the character to remove with htmlspecialchars,but without any results.

What I'm doing wrong?

-EDIT-
This is the full code of my script:

```
$title = 'Super Mario Galaxy 2 - Debut Trailer'; // Fetched from the DB, in the DB the character is - (minus) not &ndash;

$new_title = str_replace(' - ', '', $title);
$new_title = str_replace(" - ", '', $title);
$new_title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&ndash;'),'',$title);
```

No one works.
Basically the problem is that in the DB the dashes are stored as "minus" (I enter the value with the minus key) but for a strange reason the output is &ndash ;

I'm running on Wordpress and the charset is UTF-8, the same for the DB collation.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with your sample code. If it's an encoding problem, you might need to save it into a file and upload it somewhere...

Comment: The code you've pasted works.  So clearly your problem is something else...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try something like this:

```
str_replace(html_entity_decode('&ndash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '', $string);
```

My guess is it's not really an ndash, but a very similar character.  I'd suggest pulling the byte values of each character in the string to see what it looks like:

```
function decodeString($str) {
    //Fix for mb overloading strlen option
    if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) { 
        $len = mb_strlen($str, '8bit');
    } else {
        $len = strlen($str);
    }
    $ret = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $ret .= dechex(ord($str[$i])).' ';
    }
    return trim($ret);
}
```

That'll convert the string into the individual byte encodings (turn it into a hex string like `48 65 6C 6C 6F` (`Hello`).  Check to see the dash in both cases is in fact the same character.  If you see "2D" where the dash is, that's a literal minus sign...  If you see the three byte sequence `E2 80 93`, that's `&ndash;`.  Anything else means a different character...

**EDIT:**
And if you see `26 6E 64 61 73 68 3B` that mens a literal `&ndash;`, so you'd need to do `str_replace('&ndash;', '', $str);`

Comment: With your first str_replace all things works! Now I'm curious why I output ndash instead of minus... I'll take a look at the hex strings.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, then the problem was that your source code file was not actually UTF-8 (The character you thought was ndash was something else)...  If you use the UTF-8 character set, always add the `'UTF-8'` parameter to `html(_entity_decode|entities|specialchars)`

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

i've managed to do this by calling `remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );` in functions.php an then you perform a `str_replace` or whatever by "-" sign;

Comment: I got `Fatal error: Call to undefined function remove_filter() `

Answer (score 1):

There's `&ndash;` (–) and there's the *minus* sign (-). Make sure you are not trying to replace the wrong character.

Comment: I'm sure that is &ndash , I've looked at the html source.

Comment: If you mean a literal `&ndash;`, first sAc's solution should apply. Are you escaping output with `htmlentities()`? Do you replace before or after escaping?

Comment: No to both question. It's very strange. I'm going to update the OP with the exact code I have.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and nothing worked. but in the end with the help of http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

this code did work for me

```
        $arr1 = explode(",","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F");
        $arr2 = explode(",","B,C,D,E,F");

        foreach($arr2 as $t1){
            foreach($arr1 as $t2){
                $val = $t1.$t2;
                $desc = str_replace(chr(hexdec($val)),"",$desc);
            }   
        }

        // if need removing individual value
        $desc = str_replace(chr(hexdec('A2')),"",$desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_string = str_replace('&ndash;','',$string);
```

Or:

```
$new_string = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&ndash;'),'',$string);
```

It is basically same as:

```
$new_string = str_replace ('-','',$string);
```

Comment: I've tried all of this but with no fortune.
I really can't understand.
In the db the dashed as stored as -, not in "&ndash ;" form but when I output it shows as "&n dash"...

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution for an invalid ndash:

```
$string = str_replace(chr(hexdec('3f')), '-', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this solution worked for me:

```
$string = str_replace("\x96", "-", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has tried all of the above but still having no joy then this worked for me (from a WordPress `get_the_title()` function)

```
$new_string = str_replace('&#8211;', 'or', $string);
```