# Replace weird char that looks like &ndash;

Tags: php, character-encoding, char, character

I found a character I need to convert to a minus sign (-).

I found this [Can't remove special characters with str_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168392/cant-remove-special-characters-with-str-replace).

so I tried the function decodeString on my char which gave me this:

```
65 75 72 6f 43 6c 69 6e 69 78 20 96 20 49 6d 70 6f 74 65 6e 73.
```

Does anybody know how to convert it?

Comment: Where are you getting the string from?

Comment: The `96` is the character you want to replace (I'm guessing, since it is > 0x7F), try `str_replace("\x96", '-', $str)`

Comment: Oh, can you please verify that it is actually `&ndash;`?

Comment: Alright, that worked! Cheers. I said that it looks like one

Comment: @DaveRandom submit your answer! :)

Comment: Decoding the rest of the string proved interesting, too (-: