# str_replace does not work on characters: < , > and "

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I'm wanting to remove the following characters from my string and replace them with nothing. I've used `test` to replace them just so I can test it's working. Yes the script file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

`<` , `>`, `"`, `'` and `` ` ``

I've used a simple str_replace but for some reason only the removal of `'` works - all the rest remain.

```
$title = str_replace('"',"test",$title);
$title = str_replace("'","test",$title); // this one works
$title = str_replace("<","test",$title);
$title = str_replace(">","test",$title);
$title = str_replace("`","test",$title);
```

Is there a better way to remove just these characters?

Edit: Have tried to use the character entity instead, still doesn't work:

```
$title = str_replace('"',"test",$title);
$title = str_replace("'","test",$title); // this one works
$title = str_replace("<","test",$title);
$title = str_replace(">","test",$title);
$title = str_replace("`","test",$title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&gt;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '', $title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&lt;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '', $title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&quot;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '', $title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&grave;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '', $title);
```

Comment: fyi: you can also use multiple needles: `$title = str_replace(array('"', "'", '<', '>', '`'), 'test', $title);` you could also post that string

Comment: Post the string. Or better, post the output of `echo bin2hex($title);`

Comment: Try the solution posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168392/cant-remove-special-characters-with-str-replace

Comment: Maybe `"` is written as `&quot;`

Comment: I have tried using the entity instead (see OP) but still it won't replace these chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using `preg_replace` instead:

```
echo preg_replace("~'|<|>|:~", "",$title);
```

However it's important to NOT use htmlspecialchars on this post var or it won't catch `<` and `>`