# php - How can replace "<" in a string with a space? Its not outputting via HTML correctly

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to remove a less than sign form a string in php. So:

```
$needle = "<";
$heystack = str_replace($needle,'',$heystack);
```

That works with `a-z` characters but isnt working with an `<`

Comment: `var_dump($heystack)` before. Maybe it isn't a `<` but `&lt;`

Comment: almost the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883049/how-to-remove-dash-form-any-string-using-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't remove special characters with str\_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168392/cant-remove-special-characters-with-str-replace)

Comment: you should use `file_put_contents( "test.txt", $heystack );` to check you text, because `var_dump()` in a browser could also show you the `&lt;` as `<`

Comment: Works also fine there: https://3v4l.org/adiXm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is :

```
$string = "hey <"
echo str_replace("<", "", $string);
//hey
```

---

You may need to check if `<` wasn't converted to a [html entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) `(&lt;)`

Use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) prior to replace

```
$string = html_entity_decode("hey <");
echo str_replace("<", "", $string);
//hey
```

Comment: I don't think str_repalce is a function :)

Comment: @Naruto Well, it's used right in the code-example, and the link is correct ;) Minor typo, happens to everyone from time to other :p

Comment: Corrected, thank you both.

Comment: That's SO how it should be =)

Comment: It was in fact an html entity. I changed the search to `&lt;)` and it worked fine.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out.