# PHP - Convert ΓÇô to dash

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, decode

I found some special characters in my PHP script. One of them is `ΓÇô`. It's actually a special character of a dash `-`. How should I convert it back to dash so I can process the string?

Comment: I don't know those characters but couldn't use just `str_replace` it? `str_replace('ΓÇô', '-',` or if it has other context use a regex to confirm it is on its own.

Comment: That `str_replace('ΓÇô', '-',` doesn't work. That's the mysterious part.

Comment: Seems to work here, https://eval.in/816472.

Comment: Doesn't work on mine. I am not sure why. We use the same PHP version

Comment: Does it give an error, or returns the wrong characters?

Comment: it just doesn't change anything. No error or any other reports

Comment: If you `var_dump($title);` and view the page source what is it?

Comment: The same text as before `str_replace`

Comment: `ΓÇô` != `ΓÇö` look at the `o` closely. In your language it might mean the same thing but they are different characters. The answer to your question is `str_replace(array('ΓÇô', 'ΓÇö'), '-', $title);`.

Comment: I know. Tried both, don't work

Comment: See updated comment, that wont work?

Comment: Yup, I've tried that. Didn't work

Comment: Strange, sorry I can't help. I can't reproduce the issue on any services available to me. I have a ticket on 3v4l because the code is failing there, might be an issue. You can follow here, https://3v4l.uservoice.com/forums/219058-general/suggestions/19586254-erring-code-works-on-eval-in (also might be unrelated).

Comment: It's okay. I've solved it anyway

Comment: It doesn't work here, https://eval.in/816476. Your code converts a `-` to a `-` (as I read it), doesn't seem like a solution to me.

Comment: I don't know... Whatever fix my own code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! It's inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168966/1564659)

```
$title = "Hunting, Tactical & Outdoor Optics eCommerce Store ΓÇô $595,000 ΓÇö SOLD";
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&ndash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '-', $title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&mdash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '-', $title);
```

Replacing the character right away won't work. `html_entity_decode` is definitely needed.