# PHP - Convert ΓÇô to apostrophe

Tags: php, character-encoding, encode

I found some special characters in my PHP script. One of them is `ΓÇô`. It's actually a special character of a dash `'`.

How should I convert it back to an apostrophe so I can process the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Convert ΓÇô to dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357332/php-convert-%ce%93%c3%87%c3%b4-to-dash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! It's inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533312/1564659)

```
$title = "WomenΓÇös Accessories eCommerce Business";
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&rsquo;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '\'', $title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&lsquo;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '\'', $title);
```

Replacing the character right away won't work. `html_entity_decode` is definitely needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iconv for UNIX like systems, or under Windows the Notepad++.
This happens when you use different encoding formats or from a non-binary file transfer under FTP.